# Does iPhone 2020 SE support Google Calendar at all?

Tags: iphone, calendar, ical, google-calendar

I have added shared Google Calendar's calendar to my iPhone 2020 SE's native calendar. And here is the story:

- At 9 am my boss added a meeting for 4 pm
- At 10 am I reviewed my daily tasks and I saw that meeting set for 4 pm
- **At 11 am my boss has changed it to 3 pm**
- At 3 pm I did not get any calendar notification and missed the meeting
- At 4 pm I have opened my calendar and only then I saw meeting "magically" moving from 4 pm to 3 pm

What am I missing? How can I reliable work with a calendar / system / hardware for which 4 hours is not enough to update meetings, schedules and invitations?

Comment: Which iOS version are you using?

Comment: I don't have access to this device, but I can say that I have _everything that Apple gives_. So, most likely -- current official iOS version available for iPhone 2020, bought in September 2020.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Google/Apple supports it if you're using the latest versions of iOS. Maybe some settings aren't correct on your iPhone?

Go to Settings. Scroll down to Calendar. Select Accounts. At the bottom is "Fetch New Data" Is Push turned on? Also in the list above this you will see some Accounts. What are your settings for Gmail? `Fetch` > `Manual` or `Fetch` ?

Under Settings, Cellular. Is Calendar enabled for use with Cellular? If not and you aren't near a hotspot this could cause your calendar to stop updating.

Google Calendar features that don't work on Apple Calendar;

- Email notifications for events

*Is this what you were waiting for? An event change notification?*

- Create new Google calendars
- Room Scheduler

The work around would be to use the Google Calendar App in order to get the notifications of event changes.